# SwiftUI [iPadOS]: Why TextField embedded in a Sheet generates Layout Constraints conflicts when it becomes first responder?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, first-responder

I have a weird issue when I embed a TextField in a modal (sheet). I wrote a  basic sample code to showcase the issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showSheet = false
  @State var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    Button("Show Text Field", action: {
      showSheet = true
    })
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
      TextField("Type here...", text: $text)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 60, alignment: .center)
    })
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

With this simple basic code, iPad OS generates a bunch of Layer Constraints conflicts when the TextField becomes first responder:

[image: Xcode Console]

Any idea how to fix that?
Super thanks.